# Bash script accepting values

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

How can I write a bash script that:

Accepts a directory name (and its path, if not located in the same directory as your script) as well as user's Gmail username and password and the email address the message will be sent to (as command-line parameters).

Answer (score 2):

call:

```
./bob.sh "/dir/name" "gmailuser" "password123" "bob@example.com"
```

bob.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$1"
user="$2"
pass="$3"
emai="$4"

echo "$1 $2 $3 $4"
```

any bash script can accept parameters, there's not much to it...